# Celery doesn't acknowledge tasks if stopped too quickly

Tags: python, celery

For a project using *Celery*, I would like to test the execution of a task.
I know that [the documentation advises to mock it](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/testing.html) but since I'm not using the official client I would want to check for a specific test that everything works well.
Then I set up a very simple task that takes as parameters an *Unix socket* name and a message to write to it: the task opens the connection on the *socket*, writes the message and closes the connection.

Inside the tests, the *Celery worker* is launched with a *subprocess*: I start it before sending the task, send it a `SIGTERM` when I receive the message on the *socket* and then wait for the process to close.
Everything goes well : the message is received, it matches what is expected and the worker correctly terminates.

But I found that when the tests stop, a message still remains within the *RabbitMQ queue*, as if the task had never been acknowledged.
I confirmed this by looking at the *RabbitMQ* graphical interface: a "Deliver" occurs after the task is executed but no "Acknowledge".
This seems strange because using the default configuration [the acknowledge should be sent before task execution](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html#std:setting-task_acks_late).

Going further in my investigations I noticed that if I add a `sleep` of a split second just before sending `SIGTERM` to the worker, the task is acknowledged.
I tried to inspect the executions with or without `sleep` using `strace`, here are the logs:

- [Execution with a `sleep` of 0.5s](https://pastebin.com/LXz0JFvp).
- [Execution without `sleep`](https://pastebin.com/pSCd7Qwh).

The only noticeable difference I see is that with `sleep` the worker has time to start a new communication with the broker. It receives an `EAGAIN` from a `recvfrom` and sends a frame `"\1\0\1\0\0\0\r\0<\0P\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\1\0\316"`.
Is this the acknowledge? Why does this occur so late?

I give you the parameters with which I launch the *Celery* worker: `celery worker --app tests.functional.tasks.app --concurrency 1 --pool solo --without-heartbeat`.
The `--without-heartbeat` is just here to reduce differences between executions with or without `sleep`. Otherwise an additional *heartbeat* frame would occur in the execution with `sleep`.

Thanks.

Comment: Why use `strace` here? The celery logs should tell you what's going on. Start celery with DEBUG logging and provide that output. My hunch is you'll see a log message that says something to the effect of 'restoring x unacknowledged messages'.

Comment: I used strace to have a better view of what was going on than with just debug logs.

The logs simply show that in the case the sigterm is sent just when I receive the message on the socket, the task never succeeds. Wasn't it the purpose of warm shutdown to complete tasks before terminating?

* [Logs of execution with a `sleep` of 0.5s](https://pastebin.com/evL2GNtA).
* [Logs of execution without `sleep`](https://pastebin.com/dYb8auZg).